# mongodb find using multiple field, how do I know which fields does not tally?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb 2.6 find using multiple field, how do I know which field does not tally? Is the username not tally or the courseId not tally with the data in mongodb 2.6? it just return null

```
    users.findOne({ 
        "emails.address": username,
        "courseList.courseId": courseId
    }, function (queryErr, item) {
        db.close()

        if (queryErr) {
            return res.json({ "error": true, "message": queryErr })
        } 

        // If email/courseId not exist
        if (item === null) {
            return res.json({ "error": false, "message": "username/courseid is incorrect" })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** condition in your query because as it stands, the query is doing an implicit AND logic hence MongoDB is will look for documents which satisfy BOTH conditions; if any of the expressions evaluates
to false then MongoDB will return null so there is no way you would know which field tallies or not from a null result.

The **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator in this case would guarantee at least a document should any one of the query expressions evaluate to false, thus you can check for equality in your result to determine which field is incorrect though I find it a bit counter-intuitive to check which field does not tally.

Consider the following example to demonstrate this approach. It assumes the `emails` and `courseList` fields are arrays:

```
users.findOne(
    { 
        "$or": [
            { "emails.address": username },
            { "courseList.courseId": courseId }
        ]
    }, function (err, item) {
    var result = { "error": false, "message": "" };
    if (err) {
        result.error = true;
        result.message = err;
    } 
    else if (!item) {
        result.message = "Both username and courseid are incorrect";
    }
    else{
        if (item.emails.map(function (e) { return c.address }).indexOf(username) < 0 ){
            result.message = "username is incorrect";
        }
        else if (item.courseList.map(function (c) { return c.courseId }).indexOf(courseId) < 0 ){
            result.message = "courseId is incorrect";
        }
        else{
            result.message =  item;
        }
    }
    return res.json(result);
});
```